# Trouble Loading thumbnails from XML in Flash as3.0

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-3, thumbnails, gallery

I have made a gallery script that loads from xml a large image, text, and 3 thumbnails.
I am having trouble getting the thumbnails to load for some reason.
I have it so that the three thumbnails should be the previous image, the current image, and the next image. Except when you click on the current image it should load a random image. The buttons work for this but if I try to load thumbnails. They don't appear.

To load the thumbnails I have created a for loop for the array of thumbnails and the number of the image is recorded by the variable noOfImage.
I then load the other thumbnails by subtracting 1 to noOfImage if the prev button is clicked(mousewheel down or key dwn or key left) and adding 1 to noOfImage if the next button is clicked(wheel and keys...)

When I trace what the variables for the thumbnail number is they seem to be correct at times and other times I am receiving errors.

For ex.
If I load the swf and click next. The previous image is "4294967295" and the next is 1 but it outputs this "Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found."

If the value of nextImage = 1 then I dont see why it isn't loading. And why is it giving a weird number for what should be 0?  I can not tell if the problem is with the if statements I use to handle the noOfImage variables or if it has something to do with the loaders or thumbnail containers... I keep trying everything I can think of. my original version loaded all the thumbs with a for loop and worked but I was having trouble making them into clickable buttons and decided to make it simpler.

here is an example of how far i've gotten with the script.
http://soulseekrecords.org/psysci/portfolio/Portfolio.swf

below is all my code sorry if it is messy or unclear. I try my best.

```
//import tweening files
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import fl.controls.UIScrollBar;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;
TweenPlugin.activate([TintPlugin]);

//create sprite background
var backgrnd:Sprite = new Sprite();

//create array of image names
var imageNames:Array = new Array();

//create array of text descriptions
var descText:Array = new Array();

//create array for dice images
var dinames:Array = new Array();

//variable for total number of images
var totalImages:uint = imageNames.length;

//add sprite variables
var thumb:Sprite = new Sprite();
var thumb2:Sprite = new Sprite();
var thumb3:Sprite = new Sprite();

// create loaders
var smImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var smImageLoader2:Loader = new Loader();
var smImageLoader3:Loader = new Loader();

//create a variable to load the large image
var bigImageLoader:Loader = new Loader();

//create variables for the image #
var noOfImage:int;
var prevImage:uint;
var nextImage:uint;

//create random number var
var randomNumber:uint;

prevImage = 0;
nextImage = totalImages;

noOfImage = -1;

// add sprite to display list
addChild(thumb);
addChild(thumb2);
addChild(thumb3);
thumb.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
thumb.graphics.drawRect(25, 325, 75, 75);
thumb.graphics.endFill();
thumb2.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
thumb2.graphics.drawRect(125, 325, 75, 75);
thumb2.graphics.endFill();
thumb3.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
thumb3.graphics.drawRect(225, 325, 75, 75);
thumb3.graphics.endFill();
thumb.alpha = 1;
thumb2.alpha = 1;
thumb3.alpha = 1;
thumb.addChild(smImageLoader2);
thumb2.addChild(smImageLoader3);
thumb3.addChild(smImageLoader);
smImageLoader.y = 325;
smImageLoader2.y = 325;
smImageLoader3.y = 325;
smImageLoader.x = 25;
smImageLoader2.x = 125;
smImageLoader3.x = 225;

//Scroll Variables
var scrollBarAdd:Boolean = false;
var scrollBar:UIScrollBar = new UIScrollBar();

var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("portfolio.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event)
{
    myXML = new XML (e.target.data);
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < myXML.img.length() ; i++)
    {
        imageNames.push(myXML.img[i].text());
        descText.push(myXML.txt[i].text()); 
        dinames.push(myXML.imgd[i].text());
    }
    totalImages = imageNames.length;
}

//add background color sprite
addChild(backgrnd);
setChildIndex(backgrnd,0);

//add background properties
backgrnd.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
backgrnd.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 900, 500);

//add background image
var backrobe:Loader = new Loader();
addChild(backrobe);
backrobe.x = 0;
backrobe.y = 0;
backrobe.load(new URLRequest("images/background.png"));

//add bigImageLoader to the display list
addChild(bigImageLoader);
bigImageLoader.x = 225;
bigImageLoader.y = 25;

//add buttons fwd and rev
var forward:fwd = new fwd();
var reverse:rev = new rev();
addChild(forward);
addChild(reverse);
forward.x = 155;
forward.y = 365;
reverse.x = 33;
reverse.y = 365;

forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mseovr);
reverse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mseovr2);
forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mseout);
reverse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mseout2);
function mseovr (event:MouseEvent){
    TweenLite.to(forward, .1, {alpha:.5});
}
function mseovr2 (event:MouseEvent) {
    TweenLite.to(reverse, .1, {alpha:.5});
}
function mseout (event:MouseEvent){
    TweenLite.to(forward, .1, {alpha:1});
}
function mseout2 (event:MouseEvent) {
    TweenLite.to(reverse, .1, {alpha:1});
}

//Variable Key Press Function
var rkey:uint = 39;
var lkey:uint = 37;
var ukey:uint = 38;
var dkey:uint = 40;

//create a textField
var myText:TextField = new TextField();

//add text box to display list
addChild(myText);
myText.width = 200;
myText.height = 340;
myText.x = 5;
myText.y = 5;
myText.wordWrap = true;
myText.multiline = true;
myText.selectable = true;

var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            format.font = "Arial";
            format.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            format.size = 20;
            format.underline = false;
            myText.defaultTextFormat = format;

//add button
var hotSpot:hotspot = new hotspot();

//add button to display list
addChild(hotSpot);

//Set button x and y position
hotSpot.x = 92;
hotSpot.y = 367;
hotSpot.alpha = 0;
hotSpot.width = 50;
hotSpot.height = 50;

//set buttonmode
hotSpot.buttonMode = true;

//make sure all clicks register with the thumb itself (not inner contents)
hotSpot.mouseChildren = false;

//add click listener to the button
hotSpot.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, buttonClickHandler);
hotSpot.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseoverhotspot);
hotSpot.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseouthotspot);

function mouseoverhotspot(event:MouseEvent){
TweenLite.to(hotSpot, .1, {alpha:.5});
}
function mouseouthotspot(event:MouseEvent){
TweenLite.to(hotSpot, 1, {alpha:0});
}

function buttonClickHandler (event:MouseEvent) 
    {
        randomNumber = Math.random()*3;
        noOfImage = randomNumber;
        loadersnlist();

    }

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, upmouse);

function upmouse(event:MouseEvent) 
    {
        if (event.delta == 3)
        {
            noOfImage = noOfImage + 1;
                if (noOfImage == totalImages)
                    {
                        noOfImage = noOfImage - totalImages;
                    }

        }
            if (event.delta == -3)
                {

                    if (noOfImage == -1 || noOfImage == -2)
                        {
                        noOfImage = totalImages;
                        }
                            if (noOfImage == 0)
                                {
                                    noOfImage = noOfImage + totalImages;
                                }
            noOfImage = noOfImage - 1;
                }
        loadersnlist();

    }

forward.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fwdclck);
    function fwdclck (event:MouseEvent)
    {
        noOfImage = noOfImage + 1;
        if (noOfImage == totalImages)
            {
            noOfImage = noOfImage - totalImages;
            }
        loadersnlist();
    }

reverse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, revclck);

function revclck(event:MouseEvent) 
    {
        if (noOfImage == -1 || noOfImage == -2)
            {
            noOfImage = totalImages;
            }
        if (noOfImage == 0)
            {
            noOfImage = noOfImage + totalImages;
            }
        noOfImage = noOfImage - 1;
        loadersnlist();
    }

//Key Right Arrow Event
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyright);

function keyright(event:KeyboardEvent)
{

    if (event.keyCode==rkey || event.keyCode==ukey) 
        {
            noOfImage = noOfImage + 1;
            if (noOfImage == totalImages)
                {
                noOfImage = noOfImage - totalImages;
                }
            loadersnlist();
        }
}

//Key Left Arrow Event
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyleft);

function keyleft(event:KeyboardEvent){

    if (event.keyCode==lkey || event.keyCode==dkey) 
        {
            if (noOfImage == -1 || noOfImage == -2)
                {
                noOfImage = totalImages;
                }
    if (noOfImage == 0)
        {
        noOfImage = noOfImage + totalImages;
        }
        noOfImage = noOfImage - 1;
        loadersnlist();
        }
}

function scrollerthing ()
    {
        if (myText.textHeight > myText.height)
        {
            scrollBar.scrollTarget = myText;  //assign the target of the scrollBar to your textfield
            scrollBar.height = myText.height;  //make the height the same as the textfield
            scrollBar.move(myText.x + myText.width, myText.y);  //Move the scrollbar to the righthand side
            addChild(scrollBar);
            scrollBar.update();
            scrollBarAdd = true;
        } else 
        { 

            if((myText.textHeight < myText.height) && scrollBarAdd == true)
                {
                    scrollBarAdd = false;
                    removeChild(scrollBar);
                }
        }
    }

function loadersnlist () 
    {
        bigImageLoader.load(new URLRequest("images/" + imageNames[noOfImage] ) );
        bigImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, tweenage);
        smImageLoader.load(new URLRequest("thumbs/" + dinames[noOfImage] ) );
        smImageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, tweenage2);
        prevImage = noOfImage - 1;
        nextImage = noOfImage + 1;
        if (prevImage <= -1){
            prevImage = totalImages;
        }
        if (nextImage >= totalImages){
            nextImage = 0;
        }
        trace (prevImage);
        trace (nextImage);
        smImageLoader2.load(new URLRequest("thumbs/" + dinames[prevImage] ) );
        smImageLoader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, tweenage2);
        smImageLoader3.load(new URLRequest("thumbs/" + dinames[nextImage] ) );
        smImageLoader3.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, tweenage2);
    }

function tweenage(e:Event)
    {
        bigImageLoader.alpha = 0;
        TweenLite.to( bigImageLoader, 5, {alpha:1, ease:Expo.easeOut} );
        myText.alpha = 0;
        TweenLite.to( myText, 5, {alpha:1} );
        myText.text = String (descText[noOfImage]);
        scrollerthing();
    }

function tweenage2 (e:Event)
    {        
        //create a variable to load small thumbnail url image        
        TweenLite.to( smImageLoader, 5, {scaleX:.6, scaleY:.6, ease:Expo.easeOut} );
        TweenLite.to( smImageLoader2, 5, {scaleX:.6, scaleY:.6, ease:Expo.easeOut} );
        TweenLite.to( smImageLoader3, 5, {scaleX:.6, scaleY:.6, ease:Expo.easeOut} );
    }
```

Comment: 4294967295 is -1 in uint format, look how it's got there.

Comment: thanks changing the var prevImage and nextImage to int fixes that part. Still not loading the thumbs tho

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there in tracing out the thumbnail value. My next step would be to trace out the actual url that you are trying to load.

Doing this will show what you are actually referencing. It looks like you are tracking the prevImage, and setting it to the number of images when it is less than 1. The array of thumbnails is zero-based though, so with 3 thumbnails, the thumbs are at 0, 1, and 2 and you are trying to load dinames[3].

Changing the loadersnlist function to
 **prevImage = totalImages-1;** should fix it.

As an aside, I'd suggest placing all your asset creation code in a layout function, and then once everything has been added to the stage then calling you loader functions to pull in the data.